# How to retieve CRM Guid using LINQ and joins?

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

We are using CRM 2011. We have Contracts with Entity Reference to Product and each Product has an Entity Reference to a Subject.  Given a Contract Guid, I need to retrieve the Subject Guid.

I am a beginner at LINQ but I coded:

```
 var subject = from s in context.SubjectSet
                                       join product in context.ProductSet
                                           on s.Id equals product.SubjectId.Id
                                       join contract in context.ContractSet
                                           on product.Id equals contract.ce_ProductId.Id
                                       where contract.Id == gContractId
                                       select s;

                foreach (var s in subject)
                {
                    newReportableAction.ce_SupergroupRegarding =
                    new EntityReference(Xrm.Subject.EntityLogicalName, new Guid(s.Id.ToString()));
                }
```

This throws an error:

**AttributeFrom and AttributeTo must be either both specified or both ommited. You can not pass only one or the other. AttributeFrom: , AttributeTo: ce_ProductId**

What does this error mean?
How can I get the Guid?

**Update**:

I tried breaking the query into parts to see where the error was being generated from so I had:

```
var query = from product in context.ProductSet
                            join contract in context.ContractSet
                            on product.Id equals contract.ce_ProductId.Id
```

This gives:

"The type of one of expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'"

Thank you to all who help...

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you can use the .Id property right off the entity in Linq statements. Try this instead:

```
var query = from product in context.ProductSet
               join contract in context.ContractSet
               on product.ProductId equals contract.ce_ProductId.Id
```

Notice `product.ProductId` instead of `product.Id`.

Comment: I never would have guessed this - thanks for the answer, it saved me a lot of frustration since the error message doesn't seem to be related the resolution